# How to import Facebook Pixel on NuxtJs

Tags: vuejs2, facebook-pixel, nuxt.js

I need to import the Facebook Pixel code in NuxtJs.

Answer (score 7):

You can create a file in the static repository : pixel.js, with the content given by facebook :

```
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){
    if(f.fbq)return
    n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)}
    if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n
    n.push=n
    n.loaded=!0
    n.version='2.0'
    n.queue=[]
    t=b.createElement(e)
    t.async=!0
    t.src=v
    s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0]
    s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window, document,'script',
    'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js')
    fbq('init', 'XXYOUR CODEXX')
    fbq('track', 'PageView')
```

(I do not use the noscript tag with Nuxt fully based on javascrip)

Then on nuxt.conf.js file, add the lines :

```
script:[      
            {src:'pixel.js', type: 'text/javascript'}
        ]
```

Comment: or install the nuxt FB pixel module and add in the 3 line snippet into your nuxt.config.js modules block

Comment: Do you know how to make it dynamic pixel ID? For example, www.web.com/AAA use AAA pixel, www.web.com/BBB/shop use BBB. pixel.

Answer (score 4):

You can import as plugin too.

./plugins/facebook-events.js.

```js
    /* eslint-disable */
    export default ({ app, store }) => {
      /*
       ** Only run on client-side and only in production mode
       */
      // if (process.env.NODE_ENV !== "production") return
      /*
       ** Initialize Facebook Pixel Script
       */
      if (process.browser) {
        !(function(f, b, e, v, n, t, s) {
          if (f.fbq) return;
          n = f.fbq = function() {
            n.callMethod ? n.callMethod.apply(n, arguments) : n.queue.push(arguments)
          };
          if (!f._fbq) f._fbq = n;
          n.push = n;
          n.loaded = !0;
          n.version = "2.0";
          n.queue = [];
          t = b.createElement(e);
          t.async = !0;
          t.src = v;
          s = b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];
          s.parentNode.insertBefore(t, s);
        })(
          window,
          document,
          'script',
          'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js'
          );
          fbq('init', 'XXXXXXXXX-XXXXX')
          app.router.afterEach((to, from) => {
            /*
            ** Fire a page view on each route change
            */
           console.log("fire pageview", store.state)
           fbq("track", "PageView")
          })
        }
    }
```

And import it in your nuxt.config.js, in plugins session.

```js
  plugins: [
    { src: '~/plugins/facebook-events.js' }
   ]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try removing the `<noscript>` tag.

See here for debugging: https://stackoverflow.com/a/49202327/1483977
And here for a bug:  https://github.com/vuejs/vue/issues/9724

Answer (score -2):

i can be used as ssr:false like this..

```
plugins : [
    // ssr: false to only include it on client-side
    { src : '~/plugins/vue-notifications', ssr : false },
    { src : '~/plugins/vue-slider-component', ssr : false },
    { src : '~/plugins/network', ssr : false },
    { src : '~/plugins/web3js', ssr : false },
    // {src: '~/plugins/irisws', ssr: false},
    // { src : '~/plugins/iomqtt', ssr : false }
],
```