# Nuxt Fetch run 2 times(on server and client)

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

[image]

When I try to load data from server via `fetch()` in Nuxt it loads 2 times.
When page load data render and after some second it fetches again on the client.

I tried `fetch()` in a simple About page.

```html
<template>
  <div id="app" class>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: "App",
  async fetch() {
    console.log("fetching");
  }
};
</script>
```

It log **fetching** 2 times in log.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do have 2 calls because of your missmatched SSR render:

- one call on the backend is done during the generation
- second call is done because the client side hydration failed, hence a forced one is done

You can refer to this question and look for a solution there (wrote mine): [Vuejs Error: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862591/8816585)

Once this error is fixed, it should be working great again.

Comment: It can be. It only fetch 1time  on my another nuxt project.