# Why nested nuxt link in vuetify doesn't work?

Tags: nuxt.js, vuetify.js

I am using NuxtJS with Vuetify and I have the following (shortened) component

```html
<template>
  <v-card nuxt :to="`/article/${id}`">
    <v-card-actions>
      <v-btn active-class="no-active" text nuxt :to="`/newspaper/${newspaper.latName}`">
        <v-icon>mdi-text-box</v-icon>
        {{ newspaper.araName }}
      </v-btn>
      <v-btn text class="mr-2">
        <v-icon>mdi-clock-outline</v-icon>
        {{ since }}
      </v-btn>
    </v-card-actions>
  </v-card>
</template>
```

This gives me the following warning in the browser console:

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content. This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example, nesting block-level elements inside, or missing. Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.

but the page still works and navigation still works too. If I replace one of the nuxt link with a function triggering a router push the warning goes away.

Why does this happen?

**EDIT: This is how I use this component**

```html
<template>
  <span>
    <ArticleCard
      v-for="(article, i) in articles"
      :key="i"
      v-bind="article"
    ></ArticleCard>
  </span>
</template>
```

Comment: What do you have in the DOM? Can you double-check the HTML generated by all of this?

Comment: nesting links is invalid hence the error, using nuxt links, :to etc it will essentially render <a href="/article/1"><a href="/newspaper/">...</a></a> your see this from the dom in devtools

Comment: So in order to implement it I would be forced to do it the router push way right?

Comment: @LawrenceCherone I've tried to have 2 `nuxt-link`nested and it did not produced any error so far. Looks wrong but no DOM warning, this is maybe not consistent or only triggered on a larger scope. Using the HTML validator of W3c may help diagnose this one I guess. @hamza the solution here, is to either change your HTML structure to have something valid or hack the thing with a `router.push` yeah (not the best way to deal with it IMO).

Comment: Yeah, just double-checked on W3C and it's indeed forbidden as expected. Nuxt might recover by itself on some situations I guess.

Comment: so it needs to be hacked... Thank you all for all of your help!

Comment: IMO, you can avoid hacking it and make it clean but you choose how to handle it at the end.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do have 2 things here:

- DOM hydration issue, here is a [related question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862591/8816585) with all the available details. Feel free to read it and come back to me after if it is **really** not working. But mainly, inspect the DOM with your devtools and try to see what is generated/hydrated.
- you're probably not using the `:to` prop properly here. Here is the [Vuetify documentation](https://vuetifyjs.com/en/api/v-btn/#props) which is basically saying that you can check [Vue router's :to prop](https://router.vuejs.org/api/#to). This one is to be used like `:to="'home'"` or `:to="{ name: 'name' }"`. I'm not sure of the content of `buttonLink` but be sure that this is following the required object/string.

Comment: Thank you. Yes I have already followed debugging steps in the mentioned SO question, it didn't solve my issue, I couldn't find any markup problems. Then I started a process of locating what exactly triggers the warning, and I found out that if i remove one of the ```:to``` the warning disappears. The way I am using the :to tags is like this ```:to="/desired/path"```. I will try to use the notation mentioned in the docs and see if it will solve the issue

Comment: So I have now changed them to ```:to="{path: `/article/${id}`}"``` but it didn't solve the problem

Comment: As for the DOM hydration issue, you'll need to provide us more info. Do you have something inside of your `v-btn`? A lot of use-cases are given in the link above. I tried to nest a `nuxt-link` inside of another one, it's doing okay. But it may depend of the structure around it I guess @HamzaMogni

Comment: sorry that was a typo in my comment, this is how im using it ```:to="`/article/{$id}`"```

Comment: as for what I have inside the v-btn, I have just edited my question to include it