# The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content in Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, buefy

- [The other answer covered how to debug this which I did](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re/)
- I am getting this error and I am not able to determine what is causing it. I have checked the HTML markup and doesn't seem to be the source of this issue
- I am using Nuxt with SSR in my code
- [Here is the codesandbox link with the actual error in it](https://codesandbox.io/s/news-list-search-bug-0vg0h?file=/pages/index.vue)

Really appreciate if anyone can tell me what is causing this error

```
The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.
This is likely caused by incorrect HTML markup, for example nesting block-level elements inside <p>, or missing <tbody>. 
Bailing hydration and performing full client-side render.
```

Comment: Hi, what did you tried so far? There is a lot of ideas on where to find the issue. Commenting and toggling some block may help.

Comment: @kissu only thing I tried so far is client-only block and it works but my question is why is it doing that? is this a buefy specific thing, without client-only why wont it work

Comment: My answer there gives examples and link to an article explaining it from the ground up.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs Error: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, the reason for *The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content* is probably the use of randomness - more specifically the usage of `getRandomString` function in the `NewsList.vue` component to generate unique ID's

As @kissu pointed out in his [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/381282)

> any random is risky

`new Date()` inside `NewsListItem.vue` will cause problem too as the resuting `Date` object will be different on server and the client causing client side VDom difference from the HTML generated by server...