# Nuxt Apollo Client doesn't fetch the data after <NuxtLink> navigation only on page refresh

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, apollo-client, vue-apollo

This configuration creates behavior where data is refreshed only on full page refresh but it grabs data from cache if the page is opened through `<NuxtLink to='/test' />`

**apollo.config.js**

```js
export default context => ({
  httpEndpoint: 'https://test.hasura.app/v1/graphql',
  getAuth () {
    return context.store.state.auth.token ? `Bearer ${context.store.state.auth.token}` : null
  },
})
```

**test.vue**

```html
<template>
  <div v-if="users">
    users: <pre>{{ users }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import testQuery from '~/apollo/queries/test.graphql'

export default {
  apollo: {
    users: {
      query: testQuery,
      prefetch: true,
    },
  },
}
</script>
```

**testQuery.graphql**

```
query testQuery {
  users {
    phone
  }
}
```

The problem can be solved by using different fetch policy:

`fetchPolicy: 'no-cache // doesn't  cache the data'` 
`fetchPolicy: 'netowrk-only' // executes query without checking the cache result gets stored in cache`

however, that creates hydration problems even if `prefetch: true`

How should I prevent inconsistencies with the server data?

Comment: Do you want to still keep the Apollo cache? If not, use `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'`.

Comment: Don't have a need to use cache. But `fetchPolicy: 'network-only'` and `fetchPolicy: 'no-cache'` creates hydration errors

Comment: Hydration errors? Can you tell us more on this one?

Comment: First, fetch from the server returns no data even if `prefetch: true`. Hydration error: `The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content.`

Comment: Not sure what you're doing in your `fetch()` hook, meanwhile the second issue is related to this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585 And it's the same, with no code we can't help you find the actual issue here.

Comment: Read the Lichter article a while ago. The hydration error is caused because the server is getting different data than the client does. just want to figure what is the reason for that. Not using native Nuxt `fetch()` the request is made with the code you see in the question.

Comment: Wrapping code that causes hydration errors is not a solution here, because in this case the server see the same data as the client does

Comment: Please `@kissu` me if you want me to be notified. Never told that this was a solution. Can you please show us the rest of your code? Hard to know what you're doing with your Apollo here.

Comment: Also, do you see the correct data being fetch here (double-check in the network tab)? Isn't it a matter of data not being loaded yet? Maybe try to see if `users.length` since an empty array is truthy.

Comment: Also, the documentation tells you that you do have a friendly helper: https://apollo.vuejs.org/guide/apollo/queries.html#loading-state You should probably try this one out: `<div v-if="$apollo.loading">Loading...</div>`