# Vuex-presistedstate error in nuxtjs, Im using vuex-presistedstate version 4.00 and nuxtjs 2.15.3

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

[image: this is the error I getting]

Im attaching the error snapshot with this code.

my persistedState.client.js looks like this:

```js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({ store }) => {
  createPersistedState()(store)
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs Error: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re)

Comment: The error is not related to `vuex-persistedstate` anyhow here. It's a DOM issue as linked in the comment above. On top of it, your issue is located near `toLowerCase`, this is the code snippet you need to provide us actually.

Comment: but I dont know where can I found the code

Comment: Okay, if you don't have any other code written by yourself, this is probably related to the package itself. Did you checked this answer? https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/54#issuecomment-329963248 Maybe this github issue too: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/130 Or even this one: https://github.com/robinvdvleuten/vuex-persistedstate/issues/151 ?

Comment: Thanks for your time but I checked all these and Im not using cookies

Comment: ? this is not related to cookies. The issue is elsewhere.

Comment: any help possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm using `"vuex-persistedstate": "^2.5.4"` in `"nuxt": "^2.15.8"` and this
code works for me

```js
import createPersistedState from 'vuex-persistedstate'

export default ({ store }) => {
  window.onNuxtReady(() => {
    createPersistedState()(store)
  })
}
```