# Getting error "DOMException: Failed to execute 'appendChild' on 'Node': This node type does not support this method." in nuxt

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

[image: Refer to this image for error screenshot]

Getting this error in production mode only. Then i need to clear the application data to get rid of this. Does anyone know what is causing this error?

I am using vue with nuxt.

Comment: Hi, not sure how you expect us to find out what is wrong here. Please give us some details, like a `package.json`, `nuxt.config.js` and try to narrow down where this error actually comes from or even better: a [repro]. At the end, show us that you did some effort before posting here. In the meantime, please read this one: https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862591/8816585 PS: the more you put into a question upfront, the faster you'll get your issue solved.