# Client-side rendered virtual DOM tree mismatching server-rendered content

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, vuex

I'm displaying an element in my component depending on a store state value. Getting this error:

> [Vue warn]: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching
> server-rendered content.

What am I doing wrong?

Component:

```
<template>
  <div v-if="open">
    ...
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import { mapState } from 'vuex'
export default {
  computed: {
    ...mapState({
      open: state => state.dropdown?.open ?? false
    })
  }
}
</script>
```

Store:

```
export const state = () => ({
  open: false
})
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vuejs Error: The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re)

Comment: Hi, did you found my linked answer relevant?

Comment: Thanks, actually it was the use of https://www.npmjs.com/package/vuex-persistedstate that was creating mismatches as I'm building the store of my app.

Comment: @drake035 So how did you get around it? I need vuex-persistedstate, so can't exactly just get rid of it.

Comment: @SeriousLee all the possible details are already given in my initial comment. You will have plenty of solution and ways to get around.