# B-Modal is Opening Two Times Vue

Tags: vue.js, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal, bootstrap-vue

I am using Bootstrap-vue and targeted a b-modal with the `<li>` like this. But it opens the modals two times with one click

```
 <li>
     <a class="dropdown-item" v-b-modal.modal-2 >Modal</a>
  </li>
```

and Here is my modal

```
<b-modal id="modal-2" title="BootstrapVue">
    <p class="my-4">Hello from modal!</p>
  </b-modal>
```

Comment: Do you have that `<b-modal>`  component inside a `v-for`? Or perhaps just a modal with the same id two times?

Comment: no its just a outside <ul> and <li> and this component don't have v-for , and the modal is declared just once

Comment: And you aren't using that component multiple times?

Comment: Do you have any warning in your console? Something like this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re

Comment: Fixed . Thank You Everyone. Actually the modal was in Header in component and the header component was used 2 times. that was the problem