# Generate random word form one string value in data nuxt js

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js

I need help. In my project (Vue Nuxtjs) I am fetching some random word which generate in my backend Laravel application through api response. I have to Generate random multiple word form one string value in data which I get from my axios route.

this is my data property.

```
data() {
    return {
        playWord: [],
        results: [],
    }
},
```

Response
[image]

And Axios

```
  async fetch() {
    const {
        data
    } = await this.$axios.get(`words/${this.$route.params.play}/play`);
    this.playWord = data.word

},
```

I have been trying with Mounted , which give me only one random value.

```
 mounted() {
    console.log(this.$route.params.play);

    var characters = 'watermelon';
    var result = ""
    var charactersLength = characters.length;

    for (var i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
    }
    return this.results = result

    console.log(result)

},
```

And method

```
    methods: {
    ply() {
        var characters = 'watermelon';
        var result = ""
        var charactersLength = characters.length;

        for (var i = 0; i < i; i++) {
            result += characters.charAt(Math.floor(Math.random() * charactersLength));
        }
        return this.result = ply
    },

},
```

How can I execute my required

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand. Could you please show us an answer of what you do have right now and what you would like to have at the end?

Comment: I have a string value from data . I want  to generate multiple value from one string value. 
like "orange", and generate multiple like  "ornage", "oregn", "anorge".

Comment: What would be the conditions? Same length at the end? Moving letters only (one or any) or duplicating them too? How much variants do you want at the end? Unique duplicates? Do you want only some variants or all the possible ones?

Comment: I  want  Same length & moving letters (any) only., some variants ( mostly 4)

Comment: i need  multiple value from one string value. like "orange", and generate multiple like "ornage", "oregn", "ograne" . like fist two &  last one  character will be same it will change only others character & need one original value

Comment: This is probably better suited into another question. Could you create one and list what you would expect as an **input** and as an **output** please?

Comment: yes , i can do that

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244002/discussion-between-tanvir-hasan-emon-and-kissu).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will give you 30 variants (or less, depending of the random) of a single `baseWord`

```html
<template>
  <div>
    <pre>total words: {{ result.length }}</pre>
    <pre>actual list: {{ result }}</pre>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  data() {
    return {
      baseWord: 'orange',
      result: [],
    }
  },
  mounted() {
    const randomVariants = [...Array(30)].map(() =>
      this.baseWord
        .split('')
        .sort(() => 0.5 - Math.random())
        .join('')
    )
    const variantsWithoutInitialWord = randomVariants.filter(
      (word) => word !== this.baseWord // removes 'orange' if present
    )
    this.result = [...new Set(variantsWithoutInitialWord)] // removing duplicates
  },
}
</script>
```

Like this

[image]

---

One thing to keep in mind is to not use a random which is available on both server and client and insert it into the DOM, otherwise you will get a [DOM missmatch](https://stackoverflow.com/q/47862591/8816585).