# Will this error cause issues during production Nuxt3

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, pinia

I got this error below from a specific line of code where it is initially set to one value on the server and then when the client logins in it is set to a different value based on their login status.

```
[Vue warn]: Hydration text mismatch:
- Client: "Sign In"
- Server: "Sign Out" 
  at <RouterLink to="/auth" activeClass=undefined exactActiveClass=undefined  ... > 
  at <NuxtLink key=0 to="/auth" onClick=fn<handleSignOut> > 
  at <Nav class="dark:bg-darkBg dark:text-darkSecondary" > 
  at <Default > 
  at <AsyncComponentWrapper > 
  at <BaseTransition mode="out-in" appear=false persisted=false  ... > 
  at <Transition name="layout" mode="out-in" > 
  at <Anonymous> 
  at <App key=1 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>
```

I do not know why this is the case here is the code from the .vue file

```
<li class="nav-li">
  <NuxtLink to="/auth" v-if="authStore.isLoggedIn" @click="handleSignOut">
    Sign Out
  </NuxtLink>
  <NuxtLink to="/auth" v-else>Sign In</NuxtLink>
</li>
```

Answer (score 1):

That means The Text has been changed it was "Sign Out" on the server, and become "Sign In" after hydration, And that's because the value of `authStore.isLoggedIn` has been changed after hydration.

To solve it you can use cookies, to set up your authentication state on the server before hydration, and client-side processing.

Comment: Thank you I will update this!

Answer (score 0):

More details regarding this issue can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585

But mainly, the content on the server side is different from the one on the client side. As a quick comparison, you can load the page of your app with and without JS to see what is different.

Otherwise, this is a huge problem in terms of performance and can lead to weird bugs. I recommend fixing it. Not sure of the exact solution for your specific case, but `authStore` could probably be done in a way that could work on both server and client side.