# Nuxt | Nuxt generates double components

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js, nuxtjs3

I'm facing an issue with nuxt 3 where when I deployed my website using SSG, the first route which is the index route loaded 2 components so for example
if I had index.vue like this

```html
<template>
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
</template>
```

it would show like this

```html
<template>
<Component1 />
<Component1 />
<Component2 />
<Component2 />
</template>
```

and this only applies to the main route (`/`) and when I switch to any other route then come back the problem seems to be fixed but when I refresh it always generates double components.

Comment: Hydration issue maybe? Did you check the github issues? Sounds like not a so uncommon issue so far.

Comment: @kissu what do you mean by hydration?

Comment: Basically this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585 It's the fact that your template from server side is "merged" on the client-side. Google for it.

Comment: I'm not using server-side rendering, I'm using SSG, @kissu

Comment: Still, the same applies. It's "SSR" in the generic way aka, everything that is basically not an SPA so SSR, SSG, ISR, Edge etc...

Comment: I didn't see any of these warns, the only warn I see is Hydration completed but contains mismatches.

Comment: Maybe the wording has changed a bit but it's exactly the same thing/reasons/solutions as what I've shared.

Comment: Well, I've tried all of the solutions you said, sadly none worked.

Comment: Some more context is then needed IMO.

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a late answer, but for the sake of people who have fallen into this problem.
nuxt sometimes mixes or merges the DOM, so you must make sure that the DOM appears completely, or using client-only will prevent this error.
Or use onMounted with v-if, to make sure the component is fully visible.
Even if it is SSG it has the same principle as SSR.

Comment: SSG and SSR are based on the server yes, as stated in the above comments. And Nuxt does not do stuff randomly if you have a DOM mismatch, there is [a very good reason](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585) for such thing, it's not a thing that can casually happen.

Comment: I had the same error. I fixed it using v-if and onMounted. This error occurs in path (/) only. I copied the same page content to other pages. It works normally. I will investigate the problem specifically where it is located and provide detailed information.

Comment: @NoxusDraven any news on this one? I have the same issue