# Vue is missing server side rendered DOM, doubling it and throwing hydration node mismatch

Tags: python, vue.js, flask, server-side-rendering, hydration

browser build and python (flask) backend. As far as I understand everything should work, the DOM is identical in both and doesn't change after that, but vue ignores the server-side rendered DOM and generates it from scratch. What surprises me even more is the fact that it does not delete the server's initial rendered DOM, but doubles it in exactly the same way.
How to make vue work with prerendered dom?

console message:

```
vue.esm-browser.js:1617 
[Vue warn]: Hydration node mismatch:
- Client vnode: Symbol(Comment) 
- Server rendered DOM: " " (text) 
  at <RouterView> 
  at <App>
```

```
Hydration complete but contains mismatches.
```

Minimal, Reproducible example:
[on code pen](https://codepen.io/MarcelDev-u/pen/qBYgPZz?editors=1001).
My code is quite complex and messy so I isolated the bug to html and js only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turned out that the issue for me was formating...

It was working:

```
<div id="app">{{ server rendered html }}</div>
```

It was not:

```
<div id="app">
    {{ server rendered html}}
</div>
```

Comment: Not using SFC I guess?

Comment: Yes, pure JS communicating with the Python backend.

Comment: Hence why the compiler is not catching that one back.

Answer (score 0):

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585) is explaining the use case with a Nuxt configuration but is totally valid for your code too.

The issue here being that you probably have:

- some hardcoded HTML string
- SSR content generated by Vue
- client-side hydrated content by Vue

All of them can have the same content, they will still not behave properly if some of them need to overwrite the previous one.

If you make your markup like this

```html
<div id="app">
  <h1></h1>
</div>
```

You will not have any issue because it will only keep Vue SSR + client-side Vue and it will be plugging itself to the `app` id.

If it was in another context, I would recommend disabling JS to try that one out or clicking on "View page source" with your mouse but you will not have a clean result on Codepen.

SSR is a broad topic with a lot of qwirky issues, I recommend that you try that with either Nuxt or at least an SFC Vue setup with Vite to get the full scope and an easier time debugging the whole thing: https://vuejs.org/guide/quick-start.html#creating-a-vue-application

Trying out in Codepen is nice but will add more sneaky things I'd say.
So don't spend too much time trying to fix that in this context, try directly into your VScode editor with some Vue devtools for a full explanation of what's happening.

Comment: at this point i think it's because of my weird python x vue setup as it doesn't work even though i simplified the templates to a single non-reactive h1 tag. I need to try the build tools or at least some other technology like react

Comment: @Marcel here it goes further than just not being reactive. I recommend sticking to only one framework, especially if you want to understand how each of them works on SSR. React and Vue behaves quite differently in terms of lifecycle + SSR.

Comment: I had a very specific case and wanted to simplify my work this way, but it turns out that I have to use vue cli and leave api in python. I try to debug it for a little more, just to understand what happend, if i get anything i share it here.

Comment: @Marcel yeah it's better to just split the two of them: Vue as SPA + Python as API.

Comment: Try `v-html` as well. Details: I had the same original error as well, and the solution was simply to use `<span v-html="myHardCodedThing"></span>` instead of `{{ myHardCodedThing }}`. No more _"Hydration complete but contains mismatches"_. Context: I'm passing my package.json version number through nuxt config, accessing it in my app.vue, then passing it into my pinia store, then showing the version number in a couple of components in my app.