# Nuxt3 Dynamic Asset Import

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vite, nuxtjs3

I'm using Nuxt `v3.0.0-rc.12`.

I have a component that needs to show an image, but the image path changes based on the `image` prop:

```html
<template>
  <img alt="" :src="resolvedImage">
</template>

<script setup>
import { computed } from 'vue'

const props = defineProps({
  image: {
    default: '',
    type: String
  }
})

const resolvedImage = computed(() => {
  return props.image ? new URL(props.image, import.meta.url).href : ''
})
</script>
```

And I use this component like that:

```html
<my-component image="../assets/somefolder/filename.png" />
```

I've read in the [Vite docs](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url) that the correct way to do that is with `new URL(url, import.meta.url)`. It works, but not in the first page load (because SSR).

I get this warning and the image is not displayed.

[image: nuxt warning]

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Check that one for various reasons as of why this is happening: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585 As of how to solve it, I'm not fully sure here but you could check the difference by either disable the JS on the page (or checking the source code) VS when your app is fully hydrated to spot the differences. Props are sync, and `URL` is available on Node's side, so I guess that `computed` in Vue3 are not immediate for some reason? Maybe using a `watch` [with `immediate`](https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#watch) is the way to go to resolve the `resolvedImage` here.

Comment: Also, I recommend that you use [`~` for your assets](https://v3.nuxtjs.org/getting-started/assets/#example-1), relative links are more error-prone.

Comment: Given [vite's documentation](https://vitejs.dev/guide/assets.html#new-url-url-import-meta-url), you cannot use `import.meta.url` to build the URL because the server cannot determine the host.