# Buefy "The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content" after adding password field

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, nuxt.js, buefy

[image]

- I am using Nuxt 2 with Buefy and FontAwesome here
- All I did was add a /login route with a login form asking for email and password
- I keep getting this error "The client-side rendered virtual DOM tree is not matching server-rendered content..."

**components/auth/AppLogin.vue component**

```
<!-- https://uistore.dev/framework/buefy/form/login-form-with-image-on-left -->
<template lang="pug">
.section
  b-field.has-text-left(:label='formData.email.label', type='is-danger', message='vow')
    b-input(
      :has-counter='false',
      :maxlength='formData.email.maxLength',
      :minlength='formData.email.minLength',
      :placeholder='formData.email.placeholder',
      :use-html5-validation='false',
      key='email',
      required,
      type='email',
      v-model='formData.email.value'
    )
  b-field.has-text-left(:label='formData.password.label', type='is-danger', message='vow')
    b-input(
      :has-counter='false',
      :maxlength='formData.password.maxLength',
      :minlength='formData.password.minLength',
      :placeholder='formData.password.placeholder',
      :use-html5-validation='false',
      key='password',
      password-reveal,
      required,
      type='password',
      v-model='formData.password.value'
    )
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'AppLogin',
  data() {
    return {
      formData: {
        email: {
          label: '',
          maxLength: 320,
          minLength: 3,
          placeholder: 'john@example.com',
          value: '',
        },
        password: {
          label: '',
          maxLength: 255,
          minLength: 8,
          placeholder: '8+ characters',
          value: '',
        },
      },
    }
  },
}
</script>
```

[LINK to the full CODESANDBOX](https://codesandbox.io/p/github/slidenerd/buefy-value-error/main)

Not sure what is causing this issue, super appreciate the suggestions

Comment: Nuxt2 is dead nowadays (End of Life), consider moving towards Nuxt3. Otherwise, try to disable the JS on the page to have an easy time debugging what may cause the hydration mismatch. Always good to give a read to that one too: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47862591/vuejs-error-the-client-side-rendered-virtual-dom-tree-is-not-matching-server-re/67978474#67978474