Hydration node mismatch: - rendered on server: in nuxt 3
<ClientOnly></ClientOnly>

I face the server side mismatch node in nuxt 3 and also redirect the home page after refresh

I have already tried ssr false from nuxt.config.ts file and use
<ClinetOnly></ClientOnly>

components in my components but issues remains with same warning.
I am trying only to display the layout and two or three simple static pages with header.

Give a try to this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585

You maybe have a p tag inside of a p tag.

I can see that you have <ClientOnly> component yet you're calling <ClinetOnly> component. Could the issue be a typo?
