nuxt components rendering twice only in production
I'm on Nuxt 3, and it seems like my webpage renders some of the components twice, in both SSR (npm run build) and when I use nuxi generate. I am using an App.vue and Nuxt pages.
What's odd is that nothing is wrong with npm run dev visually, and it only shows me an error in the console when my pinia store is set. My pinia store is pretty simple, but it uses the pinia-plugin-persistedstate. Before that I was using localStorage directly and I would see the same bugs (and I could see that the build struggled with a server that didn't have access to localStorage). Here's my pinia storage, it's pretty simple:
import { defineStore } from "pinia";
import type { User } from "~/types/User";

export const useAuthStore = defineStore("auth", {
  state: () => ({
    user: null as User | null,
    isAuthenticated: false,
  }),

  persist: process.client,

  actions: {
    login(user: User) {
      this.$patch({
        user: user,
        isAuthenticated: true,
      });
    },

    logout() {
      this.$patch({
        user: null,
        isAuthenticated: false,
      });
    },

    decreaseActions() {
      if (this.user) {
        this.user.games_left -= 1;
      } else {
        console.log("decreasing action while not logged out, that's a bug");
      }
    },
  },
});

but in my code in places, I use
const authStore = useAuthStore();
const { isAuthenticated, user } = storeToRefs(authStore);

and then display components based on these things, which are reactive...
so my guess is that when it is doing this rendering thing, it has trouble with a client that can recover its persisted state, versus a server that does not have a persisted state. I tried to fix things, but nothing seem to work.
Surprisingly it also seems like I'm the only one with this issue, one would think this is a pretty common pattern no o_O?

Any errors in console? Does it also happen if you run the production build locally with preview?

from the console: 1) DeprecationWarning: fs.Stats constructor is deprecated (which I think is not from me) and 2) WARN  Using postcss.config.js is not supported together with Nuxt. Use options.postcss instead which I think is unrelated

if I run npm run preview I get "Hydration completed but contains mismatches" in the console, but no interesting debug info. Also, no double rendering that I can see. It seems to only happen in prod after doing npm run build. Also some of my form are sent twice.

I got rid of some of the double rendering (but not all) using  <client-only> around my header btw

and the double rendering only happens when I'm logged in (so when pinia is restoring persistance) AND when I refresh the page (then the component gets rendered twice). But if I browse the main page, and go to other pages, then no double rendering

OK so I reproduced that with npm run dev. I just have my data in localStorage (so pinia can recover form it) + be in the right page when I reload, then I get a bunch of hydration node mismatch. They are all basically because the server didn't have a user logged in, and the client was logged in, which doesn't display the same stuff. Should I just have <client-only> everywhere?

Not everywhere, mostly where you have the issue: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585 Depends also on what is the error.

I believe I found the answer: I have to do StoreToRefs inside onMounted!

actually, it fixes the issue but if I don't persist my store anymore the references don't work, it is soo confusing -.-

nevermind, this did not fix thing. I managed to remove ALL hydration problem by removing the persistence plugin for pinia and doing it myself AND recovering from within a onMounted. No I have no errors in dev, but rendering issues still in production...

What are the errors?

no errors anymore, just double rendering issues still

So, this problem is really annoying, I've squandered the web to find an answer and it seems like I was missing a few things:

first, when I recoverer my pinia store from localStorage or something, I had to do that within onMounted(). (Makes sense in retrospect.)
second, because I'm recovering from onMounted, I also need to make sure I'm reactive to a change of storage. As such, I had to make sure that whatever code that depended on my pinia store that was running on onMounted() was also running if the storage changed (something like watch(isAuthenticated, update); where const { isAuthenticated } = storeToRefs(myStorage);
third, use <client-only> or <ClientOnly> wrappers everywhere XD


You could use other lifecycles too probably. Because using client only kinda defeats the purpose of SSR. But SSR is quite difficult overall yes.

TBH I do not understand the introduction of SSR, I must not be the only one that constantly runs into bugs? Why push something to users if it's going to break the framework overall? It seems like it's important to figure it out without a deep understanding of the internals of Vuejs. So anyway, I'm not sure what the advantages of SSR are, because my app runs very smoothly with the ClientOnly

SSR helps with the initial speed, SEO, being able to do things on the server for performance reasons and being able to hide token in there. Mostly the same question as of: why using NodeJS if I can do JavaScript in VueJS. Different environments. So it adds complexity for sure but most of it is  handled by Nuxt. The topic still stays complex but there is not a lot to do against that, mostly the state of the current frontend ecosystem to have isomorphic apps.

I guess I don't understand why this is the default. I've worked with Vuejs for years and everything just worked, now it forces you into this hybrid app. I guess if everybody's doing that then it makes sense, but I have a rust backend so I couldn't care less about the SSR stuff

Then run Nuxt as SPA only. This is also feasible. Not like you are obliged to SSR.
