Hydration completed but contains mismatches using VeeValidate and Pinia in Nuxt
this week I'm having a weird error into my Nuxt app, it's a small app, it's only a landing page with a register form for an event, I worked on this last week and I published it and it works fine.
Now, I have to add some modifications into the register form, nothing complex, but when I ran the project locally, without update anything, and I'm getting now a hydration error into the fields .
Again, it's too weird for me because I don't update or change anything, Im running the exactly code version that is published, and if I run the build and preview cmd, I'm having the same error.
Now, the code:
Into the form I'm using this stack:

PrimeVue InputText
VeeValidate with Zod
Pinia for store the data because the form has different steps.

In my component I do this:
const registerFormStore = useRegisterFormStore();


const validationSchema = toTypedSchema(
  object({
    [DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID]: z
      .string({ required_error: 'Ingresa tu documento de identificación' })
      .min(6, 'error message')
      .max(15, 'error message')
      .transform((value) => value.trim().toLocaleUpperCase())
      .default(registerFormStore.personalInfo.documentId || '')
  })
);
const { errors, handleSubmit, defineField, setErrors } = useForm({
  validationSchema
});

const formValues = reactive({
  documentId: defineField<DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID, string>(DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID)[0]
});

<form class="flex flex-col gap-5" @submit.prevent="onSubmitForm">
      <div class="flex flex-col gap-2">
        <label for="documentId" class="font-medium">Document Label</label>
        <IconField icon-position="left">
          <InputIcon class="pi pi-id-card" />
          <InputText
            id="documentId"
            v-model="formValues.documentId"
            placeholder="Placeholder text"
            class="w-full"
            maxlength="15"
            :disabled="isLoading"
            :invalid="Boolean(errors[DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID])"
          />
        </IconField>
  
        <transition name="fade">
          <small v-if="errors[DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID]" class="text-sm text-danger">
            {{ errors[DocumentFormFields.DOCUMENT_ID] }}
          </small>
        </transition>
      </div>
    </form>

and now I'm having the hydration error:

[Vue warn]: Hydration attribute mismatch on <input class=​"p-inputtext p-component w-full" id=​"documentId" placeholder=​"Escribe tu documento de identidad" maxlength=​"15" data-pc-name=​"inputtext" data-pc-section=​"root">​ 
  - rendered on server: (not rendered)
  - expected on client: value=""
  Note: this mismatch is check-only. The DOM will not be rectified in production due to performance overhead.
  You should fix the source of the mismatch. 
  at <InputText id="documentId" modelValue="" onUpdate:modelValue=fn  ... > 
  at <IconField icon-position="left" > 
  at <DocumentValidationForm key=3 > 
  at <RegistrationComponent key=2 > 
  at <FormSection> 
  at <Index onVnodeUnmounted=fn<onVnodeUnmounted> ref=Ref< undefined > > 
  at <Anonymous key="/" vnode= {__v_isVNode: true, __v_skip: true, type: {…}, props: {…}, key: null, …} route= {fullPath: '/', hash: '', query: {…}, name: 'index', path: '/', …}  ... > 
  at <RouterView name=undefined route=undefined > 
  at <NuxtPage> 
  at <App key=3 > 
  at <NuxtRoot>

And later, all the other steps into my form are broken, for example, when I change to the next step, I load the documentId and the username, and the fields now are broken and don't take the default value:
const validationSchema = toTypedSchema(
  object({
    [PersonalInfoFormFields.NAME]: z
      .string({ required_error: 'error text' })
      .min(2, 'error text')
      .max(100, 'error text')
      .transform((value) => value.trim())
      .default(registerFormStore.personalInfo.name || ''),
    [PersonalInfoFormFields.EMAIL]: z
      .string({ required_error: 'error text' })
      .email('error text')
      .transform((value) => value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase())
      .default(registerFormStore.personalInfo.email || '')

The data into the store is OK, but into the fields not

Look that all the fields are undefined when it should be with an empty string
I already work and search about this error but I don't have any idea why it's happening. 
I'm not sure if it's related with Pinia, because the console of store installed

but the weird think is that I do not update any library version or similar.
Any help is welcome!, thanks in advance.

There is obviously some difference between the server and the client side of things. Maybe check your code for specific parts of the code that would show that the input is not in the DOM. Maybe you're doing some calls only on client-side too?

Nop, only mounting the form section and nothing more

Do you know that the mounting lifecycle is a client-side-only lifecycle? There is no DOM to mount on the server.

@kissu you are right, I had a const actualTimeStamp = ref(Date.now()); that maybe causes that error, I set it initial as 0 and latter in onMounted set the real value, it remove the hydratation message, but, now I continue with the error that all the fields are as undefined

All the values are OK into pinia (I check it into vue devtools), but in the formValues object, all are in undefined by default

Don't use Date.now() because its value will be different from the server to the client (few ms for the hydration). I am not sure for the second part and I do not use reactive either, I prefer the regular ref.

It's beause is an object with all the form fields, is the same, but the error seems to be that the pinia store was not instantiated or similar, but in the console I'm not getting any error or warn

You need to wait for the Pinia store to be populated. Don't expect your object to have any values if it's not reactive or the store comes later on.

I found that the problem is solved if I remove a refine vee-validate function (used for validate that two fields are equal), I really don't know why it was causing the glitch

All of this is probably a matter of lifecycles + priority that some packages might have. Might be fixed with a nextTick but depending on the context might not be that easy to write either.

Yes, it make sense, I'll try to reproduce it in a more simple example and try to report the bug to vee-validate and/or zod

I found that the error was caused for different things:

Using Date.now() as initial value in some ref() const, example const myVar = ref(Date.now()); DON'T do that, initialize the ref in zero and later into the onMounted set the value myVar.value = Date.now()

I was using refine for validate two form fields:


const validationSchema = toTypedSchema(
  object({
    [PersonalInfoFormFields.EMAIL]: z
      .string({ required_error: 'error message' })
      .email('error message')
      .transform((value) => value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase())
      .default(registerFormStore.personalInfo.email || ''),
    [PersonalInfoFormFields.REPEAT_EMAIL]: z
      .string({ required_error: 'error message' })
      .email('error message')
      .transform((value) => value.trim().toLocaleLowerCase())
      .default('')
  }).refine(({ email, repeatEmail }) => email === repeatEmail, {
    message: 'error message',
    path: [PersonalInfoFormFields.REPEAT_EMAIL]
  })
);

If I remove this (the refine function), all works fine, otherwise, I have the error that the fields are in undefined.
I was able to resolve my error with those steps.
Special thanks to @kissu that help me to found the errors

Here are some other possible causes for a hydration mismatch: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585

After fixing a hydration mismatch due to Date.now(), OP found that the issue was a vee-validate function.

I added a more complete answer, but thanks for the help!!
