In Nuxt 3, how do I fix the hydration error for my conditional class that is based on scrolling?
I have a Navbar component on the top edge of the page. The logic is as follows: If the user has not scrolled at all (Y offset from the top = 0), there should not be a shadow class applied. The further the user scrolls, the bigger the shadow gets.
Here is the code of my composable that returns the shadow class:
export function getShadowClassBasedOnScrollingOffset(
  alwaysDisplayOnMobile: boolean = true,
): string {
  const { y } = useWindowScroll();

  let classList = "";

  if (alwaysDisplayOnMobile) {
    classList += "shadow ";
  }

  if (y.value < 5) {
    classList += "md:shadow-none";
    return classList;
  }

  if (y.value < 10) {
    classList += "md:shadow";
    return classList;
  }

  classList += "md:shadow-lg";
  return classList;
}

In my NavBar component, its used like this:
// Setup
const getShadowClass = computed(() => {
  return props.displayShadow ? getShadowClassBasedOnScrollingOffset(true) : "";
});


// Template
<div
    class="w-full bg-white | px-4 md:px-0 py-4 transition"
    :class="getShadowClass"
>
</div>

It works as it should, but I receive the following warning related to hydration:
Hydration class Mismatch on <DOMElement>:
 
  - rendered on server: class="w-full bg-white | px-4 md:px-0 py-4 transition shadow md:shadow-none"
  - expected on client: class="w-full bg-white | px-4 md:px-0 py-4 transition shadow md:shadow-lg"

How do I fix this?

This is still a relevant answer: https://stackoverflow.com/a/67978474/8816585 Overall you do not have Window on the server hence the difference when the HTML comes to the client side and see a window, hence building a different DOM than the one passed from the server. Make a conditional to not run your function on the server.

@kissu If I do this, it will tell me for example this: rendered on server: class="w-full bg-white | px-4 md:px-0 py-4 transition"

expected on client: class="w-full bg-white | px-4 md:px-0 py-4 transition shadow md:shadow-none". The classes would always mismatch, so how do i fix this?


As stated in the linked answer you can also wrap it into a client-only. A navbar is probably not that important SEO-wise.

What bugs me on this approach, is that it could contain links to pages which would be important SEO wise, and also, it displays oddly to the user, until the navbar is rendered on client side. Unless I put in the effort to add skeletons of course. Is there no better way?

If you have some sitemap and title on your page with the given name of the page from the navbar should not be too much of a big deal. For the display oddly there is probably a way to fix it with some CSS when it comes from the server, depends on your specific situation but mostly hacking a little with CSS to fix some of those micro visuals. But there is indeed no magic to fix a hydration mismatch than trying to find a way to have the same code running on both server and client or using some hacks to let the transition more smooth. Could use Nuxt server components if no interactivity is needed.
